# JList - loop that adds elements to JList

Tags: java, jlist

I'm trying to make a loop that adds items to jlist but when I put in actionlistener it doesn't seem to be doing it...

```
textFieldSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                locations[i] = "blah";
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: are you sure the action listener is being called (did you attach it to  some element)?

Comment: Where's the JList in your code? Where are the items coming from?

Comment: its inbetween the textfield and jlist

Comment: @Rated Are you using a `ListModel` to add elements to the JList?

Comment: no im using JList<String> list_racentRaces = new JList<String>(locations);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this :

```
textFieldSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) JLISTNAME.getModel();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                    model.add(i, "blah");
                }
            }
        });
```